# Checking access database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am trying to compare the values in my dictionary which contains values/quantities to a standard database containing similar values/quantities. I want to check if the value matches the database, then check if the quantity is less than the database.

I keep getting an error when I run the code on the "Using myreader" line, with the following: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).' This is my first time using OleDBDatareader so perhaps I am doing something incorrectly. Is this not allowed, I assumed comparing a list a values in a dictionary should be possible.

```
Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\UsersTables.accdb; Persist Security Info=False"
    myconnection = New OleDbConnection(constring)
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim keepSell As String
    For Each KeyPair In colSums
        
        Dim sqlQry As String
        sqlQry = "SELECT Part,Quantity FROM PartsList WHERE Item = '" & keyPair.Key & "'AND Size= '" & keyPair.Value & "'"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
        Using myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If myreader.Read() Then
                keepSell = "Keep"
            Else
                keepSell= "Sell"
            End If
            'myreader.Close()
        End Using
        
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(KeyPair.Key, KeyPair.Value, keepSell)
    Next
```

Comment: Which line gives you that exception?

Comment: What happens if you move your database from C:\ to another directory?

Comment: The line that has "Using myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()" gives me this error... even with moving the database I get the same thing